# about differential equations's intervals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

a) 
when we have an o.d.e. like this one
$$x^2 y' = y (\ln y-\ln x+1) $$
we can divide with x easily, and then solve
$$y' = \frac y x (\ln \frac y x+1) $$
without any limitation like $x≠0$
while when we divide with $y$ or something that contains $y$, we need to check at the end 
of our solution, if $y$ is a special solution of our o.d.e.

why this happens? (limitation for $y$, but not for $x$)

b) Okay, let's say that we have an ODE for which, we have $ y(x_o)=x_1 $.
What happens with intervals of our unique solution? for example, if the solution is something like

$ y = \frac 1 x $ ,is our solution going to work in just one interval [ $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,+\infty)$]?

c) what happens with intervals, without a relationship for $y$ (general solution)

d) do you have any link for more about intervals in differential equations?

Comment: Which one of questions above is more important for you? $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

For b, you may consult [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for more points. I am posting a simpler example in which you *feel* what is going on here. Let the ODE with initial condition, $$y'=x\sqrt{y},~~y(0)=0$$ It is not hard seeing that $y_1=0$ and $y_2=\frac{x^4}{16}$ are the solutions for ODE on $I=\mathbb R$. But why we don't get a unique solution? Indeed, according to the theorem, $f_y=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{y}}$ when we set $f(x,y)=x\sqrt{y}$ and both functions $f$ and $f_y$ are not continuous on the real line unless we assume the interval to be $$I=(0,+\infty)$$ for example. In fcat, theorem tells us through any point $(x_0,y_0),~~y_0>0$ there is some interval around $x_0$ on which the ODE has a *unique* solution.

Comment: Nice hat on your head;-)+1

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$

Answer (score 0):

In (a), you definitely have $x\neq 0$ since $\ln x$ isn't even defined at 0.  If instead the equation was $x^2 y'=y\ln y$, dividing by $x$ would give you $y'=y\ln y / x^2$, which a solution of the former equation would satisfy whenever $x\neq 0$ (a limitation for $x$).

For (b), if your differential equation is dy/dx=-1/x^2 with y(1)=1, there is a unique solution on $(0,\infty)$ given by $y=1/x$.  There are multiple solutions on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, for example $y=1/x$ or $y=\{1/x$ if $x>0,  3+1/x$ if $x<0$.